# Implementing Proxy Server but gets XXS issue on SSL Servers

Tags: java, ssl, proxy

I am implementing a proxy server which will be used to security purposes, and I am implementing it in Java, using Httpclient and native Sockets. The problem comes out when using SSL connections and even normal connections, because the browswer alaways detects it as XXS/cross side scripting threats.

The main code I am using to make the traffic flow is:

```
HttpResponse response = null;

try {
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(acceptingTrustStrategy,
    SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", socket.getPort(), sf));
    ClientConnectionManager ccm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(registry);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm);
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(
            new Scheme("https", 443, SSLSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory())
    );

    if (!urlToCall.contains("http://") || !urlToCall.contains("https://")) {
        urlToCall = "https://" + urlToCall;
    }

    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(urlToCall);
    response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);

} finally {

}

InputStream is = null;

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 && response != null) {
    try {
        is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        out.writeBytes(inputStreamToString(is));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ProxyThread.LOGGER.debug(ProxyThread.LOGGER.getName(), ioe);
    } finally {
        rd.close();
    }
}
```

Is there anyone with good idea for making traffic flow with SSL or NOT?

Comment: XSS is usually not caused by a simple proxy, SSL or not. Please provide how you use the proxy from inside the browser. My guess is that you are not using the normal proxy settings of the browser but that you are doing something special which causes the problem. Please provide also the exact error messages you get. Apart from that, do proper certificate validation in your code. As it currently is the question can not be answered because it shows only some code fragment without useful context.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Steffen. Actually the problems can be viewed on this log: [link]http://constantinoit.com/proxy_log.txt , this is a exection lifecycle. I am setting the proxy sertting as the internet explorer settings or control panel, which affects all the windows network.

Comment: Looks like there are some problems with HTTP/2 too. Weird. May be I should swtich to jetty api to I can deal with http/2 connections.

Comment: I have no idea where I should get any details about the XSS errors you are talking about. The log file just shows forwarding of data. Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: Without looking at the entire code, I'm sure there is a problem with HTTPS proxying. If you intend to look at HTTPS traffic, you have to implement a man-in-the-middle decryption, which is probably not the case. If you intend to pass HTTPS traffic as-is, you need to set a proxy in the browser, and handle CONNECT requests.